# ASP.NET MVC - "Add View" Outside of the Views Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are there any changes I can make to Visual Studio to add the "Add View" dialog option to a folder other than Views? I have my website split up somewhat differently and I'd still like access to the T4 templates provided by "Add View".

To clarify:

I am not trying to change the default View Engine or do anything in code pertaining to how my Views work, I simply would like to know if there is any way to have the "Add View" context menu item display on Solution Explorer items other than just the "Views" folder. My application has an "Areas" folder which contains a "Views" sub-folder for each Area and I would like to have the "Add View" menu item available when I right click on Areas > AREANAME > Views and select "Add".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this behavior is hardcoded in *Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.dll* file.

I think you could:

- try reverse engineering this library;
- ask MVC team members for its source code.